# Flatten a loop through worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in an excel spreadsheet and need to modify it so that it only replaces the inputted data on one sheet rather than checking all sheets.

The sheet I need it to check is 'New Performance (2)'

I would love to understand the process as well as know the answer as I am trying to learn how to do more with Macros :)

```
sub terfuge
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Replacement As String
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim MatchCase As Boolean

    Prompt = "Replace Merchant ID?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Next

End Sub
```

Also, Would anybody be able to tell me how to put some form of error proofing in - the problem I have with it is that if I cancel after the first input box, it removes the defined text (i.e. replaces the defined text with blank as the replacement has;t been defined)

Any ideas how I could get it to do nothing if the user clicks on cancel?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you whant to check in the worksheets ?

Comment: Added some info on error proofing to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a particular worksheet, use Sheets("worksheet name"). You can set a worksheet to a variable in your code. In this case, it is the variable WS.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "aaa"
```

Will write aaa in Sheet1, A1

So will:

```
dim WS as worksheet
set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
WS.Range("A1")= "aaa"
```

In your loop, every sheet gets assigned to the variable WS and something happens with them. Just change the For Each loop with a single assigned worksheet:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Search As String
Dim Replacement As String
Dim Prompt As String
Dim Title As String
Dim MatchCase As Boolean

Prompt = "Replace Merchant ID?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

Set WS =  Sheets("New Performance (2)")
WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the worksheet loop.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Search As String
Dim Replacement As String
Dim Prompt As String
Dim Title As String
Dim MatchCase As Boolean

Prompt = "Replace Merchant ID?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

'Here you will set the worksheet to the sheet you want to search.
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("New Performance (2)")
ws.Activate
WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

For "error proofing" you can analyze the return.

```
Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
If Search = "" then
    Exit sub
End if
```

Or you can use a message box.

```
  ' Displays a message box with the yes and no options.
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", vbYesNo)

  ' If statement to check if the yes button was selected.
  If Response = vbYes Then
      'Do something
  Else
      'Do something
  End If

  These are the return values

    Constant    Value   Description
    --------    -----   ----------
    vbOK        1       OK
    vbCancel    2       Cancel
    vbAbort     3       Abort
    vbRetry     4       Retry
    vbIgnore    5       Ignore
    vbYes       6       Yes
    vbNo        7       No
```

Answer (score 0):

This `For` loop is iterating through each sheet

```
For Each WS In Worksheets
WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
Next
```

To make it only so that it will replace the values on one sheet, remove the for loop and use the `Worksheets("New Performance (2)").Cells...` like so:

```
Worksheets("New Performance (2)").Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

Comment: They all did come in pretty fast!

Comment: Wow I have been beat by you AND 3 others in the time to post!

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't run code you don't understand. That being said, as you're trying to learn, look at this section of your code here:

```
For Each WS In Worksheets
    WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
Next
```

This says 'Take all of the open worksheets. For Each one of these worksheets, perform the following tasks, one at a time.

To make this apply only to your specific sheet, simply change which worksheet is being looked at, like so:

```
Sheets("New Performance(2)").Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Search As String
Dim Replacement As String
Dim Prompt As String
Dim Title As String
Dim MatchCase As Boolean

Prompt = "Replace Merchant ID?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
Title = "Search Value Input"
Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Performance (2)")
WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, _
                 Replacement:=Replacement, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 MatchCase:=False
```

The explanation is that:

In the code you posted you are looping through all of the worksheets and setting the WS object equal to every sheet

So in the code that I posted I got rid of the for loop by deleting the lines beginning with for and next.
Then I set the WS object equal to the sheet "New Performance (2)"